# OS X Server - How do I clone or transfer users from an Open Directory I'm planning to disband, to another server?

Tags: mac-osx-server

I have an OS X Server I've been using for the last two years or so.

During this time it has been upgraded and fixed so many times it developed some certificate problems now turning into a gangrene.

I would like to transfer the network users in the OD, via Workgroup Manager or something, maybe even keeping their passwords if possible. I can't archive the OD and restore it since I also changed the hostname and ip of the server.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a nice method posted here https://support.apple.com/kb/PH15633:

1. First archive (backup) your current OD on the server.

   Using the Server app interface backup your current OD, clicking on the sprocket and choosing Archive.
2. Destroy the current OD. (*optional)

   sudo slapconfig -destroyldapserver
3. Create a new one from scratch on the new server.

   Using the Server app interface. Go to Open Directory on the left side and click the On button in the top right.
4. Restore the old one over the new one.

   sudo slapconfig -restoredb /full/path/to/archive.sparseimage